# Fabric js object boudaries won't update after object moved programmatically

Tags: fabricjs

There's some object (rectangle as an example) and when I change it position using js I couldn't drag it from new place, just from the old one.
There's example below. Press "MOVE" to move object and than try to drag it. It won't drag if you try to, but it will if you drag his old position.[image]

```js
var c = new fabric.Canvas('c');
c.add(new fabric.Rect({
 left: 0,
  top: 0,
  width: 40,
  height: 40,
  fill: 'red'
}));

$('#init').click(function() {
 c.item(0).setLeft(0);
  c.item(0).setTop(0);
  c.renderAll();
});

$('#move').click(function() {
 c.item(0).setLeft(100);
  c.item(0).setTop(100);
  c.renderAll();
});
```

```css
#c {
  outline: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.12/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<button id="init">
INIT
</button>
<button id="move">
MOVE
</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is occurring because , you are not updating the object­*'s* controls coordinates after changing it­*'s* position.

You need to call **[`.setCoords()`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#setCoords)** method on the object to update it­*'s* controls coordinates accordingly.

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ**

```js
var c = new fabric.Canvas('c');
c.add(new fabric.Rect({
   left: 0,
   top: 0,
   width: 40,
   height: 40,
   fill: 'red'
}));

$('#init').click(function() {
   c.item(0).setLeft(0);
   c.item(0).setTop(0);
   c.item(0).setCoords(); //<-- call this
   c.renderAll();
});

$('#move').click(function() {
   c.item(0).setLeft(100);
   c.item(0).setTop(100);
   c.item(0).setCoords(); //<-- call this
   c.renderAll();
});
```

```css
#c{outline: 1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.12/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="180" height="180"></canvas>
<button id="init">
   INIT
</button>
<button id="move">
   MOVE
</button>
```